# Enterprise Architecture not importing c++ code (reverse engineering) with type alias with 'using' in the class

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I am trying to import a c++ template class into Enterprise Architect project, but doesn't show anything after import successfully. The template class has type aliases defined, with 'using' statement. E.g.

```
using my_type_t = decltype(T::struct_mem_1);
using type_2_t = typename T_2::value_type;
```

When I remove the above aliases, then it is able to import and synchronize. So, is there any reason why it is behaving like this? And any workaround, so that I can synchronize without having to remove first the aliases and then add them back after synchronization?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless Geert will be looking during Easter I guess you should cross-post on Sparx' forum. The Sparxians (almost) don't answer here but only on their forum.

Comment: I am looking, but I don't know anything about reverse engineering C++, sorry. I would probably contact Sparx support.